# get text from aria-label using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
<span class="_1n9k" data-hover="tooltip" tabindex="-1"><a ajaxify="/ufi/reaction/profile/dialog/? ft_ent_identifier=ZmVlZGJhY2s6MzgyODczMjYzMDg5MTQy&amp;reaction_type=1&amp;av=0" aria-label="좋아요 17" class="_1n9l" href="/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/?ft_ent_identifier=ZmVlZGJhY2s6MzgyODczMjYzMDg5MTQy&amp;av=0" rel="dialog" role="button" tabindex="0"><i class="sp_KIvjPBBBAwk sx_eaca68" role="img"></i></a></span>
```

How do I get text '좋아요 17' from 'aria-label'?
I tried using get('aria-label') but it isn't work

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'aria-label'` is an `attribute` of the `a` tag that is within the `span` tag. Here is how you extract the value of the `attribute`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<span class="_1n9k" data-hover="tooltip" tabindex="-1"><a ajaxify="/ufi/reaction/profile/dialog/? ft_ent_identifier=ZmVlZGJhY2s6MzgyODczMjYzMDg5MTQy&amp;reaction_type=1&amp;av=0" aria-label="좋아요 17" class="_1n9l" href="/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/?ft_ent_identifier=ZmVlZGJhY2s6MzgyODczMjYzMDg5MTQy&amp;av=0" rel="dialog" role="button" tabindex="0"><i class="sp_KIvjPBBBAwk sx_eaca68" role="img"></i></a></span>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

span = soup.find('span', class_ = "_1n9k")

print(span.a['aria-label'])
```

Output:

```
좋아요 17
```

Comment: how can i find lots of 'aria-label' when using find_all?

Comment: Try this: ```a_tags = span.find_all('a')           for a in a_tags: print(a['aria-label'])```